# can't run `npm install -g angular/cli`

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-cli

I've recently generated a new ssh key on my mac and I can't seem to install angular/cli anymore. When I try to run `npm install -g angular/cli` I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/angular/cli.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ERROR: Repository not found.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

At the same time typescript installed perfectly fine. My npm version is 5.3.0 and node version is 8.2.1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: npm 5.3.0 has multiple issues. M not sure whether this was to, but try to downgrade to npm5. 2.0

Comment: @mehta-rohan I tried diferent version of npm and I get the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was using the incorrect repo name. It should have been:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Notice the `@`.

Comment: about to tell you that